# Capistrano fails without error message

Tags: deployment, capistrano, net-ssh

I'm having problems deploying with Capistrano. The deploy works fine from my MacBook, but when I try to run it from a server (running Debian) it fails without any error message, or at least one that I can discern. With debug mode on:

```
bundle exec cap staging deploy
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.426469 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[164f428]: establishing connection to bbos.parisleaf.com:22
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.457445 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[164f428]: connection established
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.457565 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[164e5c8]: negotiating protocol version
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.505677 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[164e5c8]: remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3'
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.505750 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[164e5c8]: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_2.9.1 x86_64-linux'
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.515288 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 840 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.515437 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 0 type 20 len 836
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.515548 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[164b4e0]: got KEXINIT from server
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.515676 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[164b4e0]: sending KEXINIT
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.515851 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 0 type 20 len 2020
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.515965 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 2024 bytes
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.516007 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[164b4e0]: negotiating algorithms
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.516119 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[164b4e0]: negotiated:
* kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
* host_key: ssh-rsa
* encryption_server: aes128-cbc
* encryption_client: aes128-cbc
* hmac_client: hmac-sha1
* hmac_server: hmac-sha1
* compression_client: none
* compression_server: none
* language_client: 
* language_server: 
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.516170 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[164b4e0]: exchanging keys
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.516383 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 1 type 34 len 20
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.516453 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.532884 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 152 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.532976 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 1 type 31 len 148
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.534509 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 2 type 32 len 140
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.534583 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 144 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.546729 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 720 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.546836 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 2 type 33 len 700
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.548450 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 3 type 21 len 20
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.548525 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.548598 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 3 type 21 len 12
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.548912 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[15a0068]: beginning authentication of `parisl5'
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.549056 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 4 type 5 len 28
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.549109 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.603794 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.603914 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 4 type 6 len 28
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.604060 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[15a0068]: trying none
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.604218 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 5 type 50 len 44
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.604288 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 68 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.620777 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 84 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.620884 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 5 type 51 len 60
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.620977 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[15a0068]: allowed methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.621045 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.none[159a294]: none failed
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.621116 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[15a0068]: trying publickey
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.621357 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[1591ec8]: connecting to ssh-agent
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.621548 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[1591ec8]: sending agent request 1 len 44
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.621663 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[1591ec8]: received agent packet 2 len 5
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.621719 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[1591ec8]: sending agent request 11 len 0
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.621791 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[1591ec8]: received agent packet 12 len 5
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.621968 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.publickey[159841c]: trying publickey (eb:20:b5:5e:1b:f0:fd:b7:df:36:21:37:3c:ed:5a:c7)
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.622136 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 6 type 50 len 348
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.622204 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 372 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.677190 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 324 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.677675 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 6 type 60 len 300
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.681739 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 7 type 50 len 620
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.682001 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 644 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.908290 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 36 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.908674 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 7 type 52 len 12
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.908821 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.publickey[159841c]: publickey succeeded (eb:20:b5:5e:1b:f0:fd:b7:df:36:21:37:3c:ed:5a:c7)
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.909278 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 8 type 90 len 44
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.909467 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 68 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.919453 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.919568 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 8 type 91 len 28
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.919704 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_open_confirmation: 0 0 0 32768
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.919809 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.channel[157fd68]: sending channel request "auth-agent-req@openssh.com"
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.919911 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 9 type 98 len 44
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.920156 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.channel[157fd68]: sending channel request "pty-req"
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.920291 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 10 type 98 len 60
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.920414 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.channel[157fd68]: sending channel request "exec"
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.920510 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 11 type 98 len 76
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.920613 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 252 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.933390 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 124 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.933511 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 9 type 99 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.933586 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_success: 0
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.933654 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.service.forward[157dae0]: authentication agent forwarding is active
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.933747 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 10 type 93 len 28
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.933831 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_window_adjust: 0 +2097152
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.933923 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 11 type 99 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:12.933979 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_success: 0
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.341594 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 140 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.341887 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 12 type 98 len 44
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.342018 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_request: 0 exit-status false
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.342293 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 13 type 96 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.342358 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_eof: 0
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.342455 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 14 type 97 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.342515 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_close: 0
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.342651 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 12 type 97 len 28
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.342889 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 13 type 90 len 44
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.342999 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 120 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.350744 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.350864 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 15 type 91 len 28
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.350969 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_open_confirmation: 1 2 0 32768
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.351257 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.channel[1561ad4]: sending channel request "exec"
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.351381 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 14 type 98 len 60
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.351510 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 84 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.359771 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 88 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.359879 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 16 type 93 len 28
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.359945 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_window_adjust: 1 +2097152
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.360032 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 17 type 99 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.360090 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_success: 1
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.364698 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 68 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.364823 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 18 type 95 len 44
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.364897 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_extended_data: 1 1 20b
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.364967 #29555] DEBUG -- net.scp[1561b9c]: stdin: is not a tty
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.476659 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.476786 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 19 type 94 len 28
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.476857 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_data: 1 1b
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.477103 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 15 type 94 len 44
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.477204 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 68 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.484968 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.485076 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 20 type 94 len 28
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.485141 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_data: 1 1b
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.485350 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 16 type 94 len 108
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.485440 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 132 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.485564 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 17 type 94 len 28
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.485631 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.540858 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.540985 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 21 type 94 len 28
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.541056 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_data: 1 1b
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.541190 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 18 type 96 len 28
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.541278 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.549673 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 140 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.549786 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 22 type 98 len 44
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.549876 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_request: 1 exit-status false
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.549975 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 23 type 96 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.550034 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_eof: 1
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.550120 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 24 type 97 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.550178 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_close: 1
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.550286 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 19 type 97 len 28
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.550637 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 20 type 90 len 44
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.550748 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 120 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.558562 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.558729 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 25 type 91 len 28
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.558809 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_open_confirmation: 2 0 0 32768
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.559094 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.channel[151f10c]: sending channel request "pty-req"
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.559211 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 21 type 98 len 60
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.559345 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.channel[151f10c]: sending channel request "exec"
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.559462 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 22 type 98 len 92
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.559566 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: sent 200 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.568305 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 88 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.568418 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 26 type 93 len 28
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.568487 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_window_adjust: 2 +2097152
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.568576 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 27 type 99 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.568634 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_success: 2
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.686413 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: read 140 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.686577 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 28 type 98 len 44
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.686655 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_request: 2 exit-status false
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.686850 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 29 type 96 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.686912 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_eof: 2
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.687034 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: received packet nr 30 type 97 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.687093 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[157fee4]: channel_close: 2
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.687186 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[164ef00]: queueing packet nr 23 type 97 len 28
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.688474 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[14e6a00]: establishing connection to bbos.parisleaf.com:22
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.718650 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[14e6a00]: connection established
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.718740 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[14e38a0]: negotiating protocol version
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.733418 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[14e38a0]: remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3'
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.733476 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[14e38a0]: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_2.9.1 x86_64-linux'
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.742420 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 840 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.742512 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 0 type 20 len 836
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.742583 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[14e2d60]: got KEXINIT from server
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.742682 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[14e2d60]: sending KEXINIT
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.742834 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 0 type 20 len 2020
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.742908 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: sent 2024 bytes
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.742949 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[14e2d60]: negotiating algorithms
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.743057 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[14e2d60]: negotiated:
* kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
* host_key: ssh-rsa
* encryption_server: aes128-cbc
* encryption_client: aes128-cbc
* hmac_client: hmac-sha1
* hmac_server: hmac-sha1
* compression_client: none
* compression_server: none
* language_client: 
* language_server: 
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.743093 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[14e2d60]: exchanging keys
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.743260 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 1 type 34 len 20
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.743338 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.759984 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 152 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.760078 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 1 type 31 len 148
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.761529 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 2 type 32 len 140
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.761602 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: sent 144 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.774158 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 720 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.774262 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 2 type 33 len 700
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.775672 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 3 type 21 len 20
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.775745 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.775818 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 3 type 21 len 12
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.776077 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[130f254]: beginning authentication of `parisl5'
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.776176 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 4 type 5 len 28
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.776228 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.831201 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.831335 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 4 type 6 len 28
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.831470 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[130f254]: trying none
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.831606 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 5 type 50 len 44
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.831675 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: sent 68 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.839770 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 84 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.839887 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 5 type 51 len 60
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.839966 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[130f254]: allowed methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.840043 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.none[130c5cc]: none failed
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.840104 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[130f254]: trying publickey
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.840290 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[12faa34]: connecting to ssh-agent
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.840429 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[12faa34]: sending agent request 1 len 44
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.840528 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[12faa34]: received agent packet 2 len 5
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.840577 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[12faa34]: sending agent request 11 len 0
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.840646 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[12faa34]: received agent packet 12 len 5
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.840772 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.publickey[12fb510]: trying publickey (eb:20:b5:5e:1b:f0:fd:b7:df:36:21:37:3c:ed:5a:c7)
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.840910 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 6 type 50 len 348
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.840977 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: sent 372 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.849281 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 324 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.849394 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 6 type 60 len 300
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.852219 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 7 type 50 len 620
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.852306 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: sent 644 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.861094 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 36 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.861238 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 7 type 52 len 12
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.861311 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.publickey[12fb510]: publickey succeeded (eb:20:b5:5e:1b:f0:fd:b7:df:36:21:37:3c:ed:5a:c7)
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.861519 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 8 type 90 len 44
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.861650 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: sent 68 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.877166 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.877294 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 8 type 91 len 28
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.877399 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[12d5af4]: channel_open_confirmation: 0 0 0 32768
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.877495 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.channel[12d5504]: sending channel request "auth-agent-req@openssh.com"
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.877609 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 9 type 98 len 44
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.877873 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.channel[12d5504]: sending channel request "pty-req"
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.878000 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 10 type 98 len 60
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.878143 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.channel[12d5504]: sending channel request "exec"
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.878243 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 11 type 98 len 172
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.878343 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: sent 348 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.887608 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 124 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.887754 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 9 type 99 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.887820 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[12d5af4]: channel_success: 0
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.887880 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.service.forward[12d2444]: authentication agent forwarding is active
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.887970 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 10 type 93 len 28
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.888034 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[12d5af4]: channel_window_adjust: 0 +2097152
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.888141 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 11 type 99 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:13.888197 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[12d5af4]: channel_success: 0
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.164267 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 68 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.164563 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 12 type 90 len 44
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.164670 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[12d5af4]: channel open auth-agent@openssh.com
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.164912 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.service.forward[12d2444]: opening auth-agent channel
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.164998 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[128d4fc]: connecting to ssh-agent
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.165154 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[128d4fc]: sending agent request 1 len 44
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.165278 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[128d4fc]: received agent packet 2 len 5
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.165473 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 12 type 91 len 28
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.165600 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.173389 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.173498 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 13 type 94 len 28
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.173579 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[12d5af4]: channel_data: 1 5b
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.173626 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.service.forward[12d2444]: data:5 on agent forwarded channel
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.174039 #29555] DEBUG -- unixsocket[128c444]: sent 5 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.174151 #29555] DEBUG -- unixsocket[128c444]: read 9 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.174245 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.connection.channel[12abac4]: read 9 bytes from client, sending over agent forwarded connection
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.174357 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 13 type 94 len 28
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.174442 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.234804 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 168 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.234938 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 14 type 94 len 108
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.235011 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[12d5af4]: channel_data: 0 86b
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.235152 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 15 type 96 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.235216 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[12d5af4]: channel_eof: 1
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.235279 #29555] DEBUG -- net.ssh.service.forward[12d2444]: eof agent on agent forwarded channel
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.235441 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: read 140 bytes
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.235534 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 16 type 96 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.235609 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[12d5af4]: channel_eof: 0
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.235720 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 17 type 98 len 44
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.235792 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[12d5af4]: channel_request: 0 exit-status false
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.235895 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: received packet nr 18 type 97 len 12
I, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.235954 #29555]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[12d5af4]: channel_close: 0
D, [2014-05-23T13:56:14.236070 #29555] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[14e60c8]: queueing packet nr 14 type 97 len 28
 INFO [f6fee6b3] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/bbos/ on bbos.parisleaf.com
 INFO [f6fee6b3] Finished in 0.916 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO Uploading /tmp/bbos/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [f306eea7] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/bbos/git-ssh.sh on bbos.parisleaf.com
 INFO [f306eea7] Finished in 0.136 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

I'm having an impossible time trying to fix this because I have no idea what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. There were two causes:

1. I had an error in my git :repo_url string (ssl://@server... instead of ssh://@server...). This caused the git-check to fail.
2. There were no helpful error messages. It turns out that – at least in my environment – cap deploy fails rather cryptically when I omit the 'bundle exec' in front of it. The error I kept getting was:

   > ```
   > $ cap production deploy
   > ...
   > DEBUG [539c31c3] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/<app>/git-ssh.sh
   > INFO [539c31c3] Finished in 0.096 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
   > ** Execute git:check
   > cap aborted!
   > fatal: No live threads left. Deadlock?
   > /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:22:in `join'
   > ```

Comment: I don't have errors or anything but `bundle exec cap deploy` helper indeed.